# Can someone identify this 'striped' stone?

Tags: geology

[image][image][image]

The stone has a raised texture on the top where the stripes are.
I'm not sure exactly where it was found.
It is not magnetic.

[image][image]

Comment: **All** your pictures are out of focus. Please make new pics, [read this](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions) and update youyr question.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I updated my description and downloaded 2 more photos, sorry they're blurry, my phone is cheap.

Comment: These are better, but did you read that guide? Go outside, take pictures out of direct sunlight, no flash. Use enough distance between phone and stone and crop the picture later - one thing people tend to do is to keep the phone too close to the object, and then it can no longer focus.

Comment: That looks a bivalve but please read the guide. Take a picture with better ligth. Marck the flower icon on your smartphone and at least provide the location. Put a rule better than a coin. For identification of the specie what paleontologist need is measures of the piece.

Comment: Where did you found it? There are "in situ" fossils and trasnported fossils. If you took in "on place" what is needed is a description of the environment where you found it. It the geological unity has a geological name, provide it, or at least a link to google maps to the specific place you found it.

Comment: Add the tag identification-request. Don't you have any idea about where thas it come? At least what was the country where this fossil was would be helpful.

Comment: @Jan Doggen: Should we put here [SOLVED:Bivalve]? Note in this case a paleontologist may identify the specie of bivalve with the second picture (form of that pattern).

Comment: @Universal_learner There is no reason *at all* to consider this solved: no answer marked correct, no upvotes, insufficient information in the question (and on hold until that is solved).

Comment: It migth be a good idea to put on hold every post like this, when the poster received the link to the guide of posting and does not do anything to force him to better edit his question. Once he knows it is a bivalve he can even do not enter more on the forum. http://peabody.yale.edu/collections/blog/2011-11-07/bivalves-vs-brachiopods-external-differences

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a shell from a bivalve of some kind, that has been worn presumably by wave action.

You may want to update your question with more context. Where did you find it? Also, your photos are all out of focus and some are overexposed, so you may want to re-take the photos. You might also want to try asking on a biology or zoology site.